# In FFMpeg Ubuntu “rtmp://url live=1” not working

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, ffserver

Trying to excute following ffmpeg command in ubuntu.

**`ffmpeg -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234 live=1" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56` **

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  8 2014 13:15:21 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/encoder/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/encoder/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/encoder/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/encoder/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 74.100 / 52. 74.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.102 / 55. 58.102
  libavformat    55. 36.102 / 55. 36.102
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[rtmp @ 0x3c5a140] Detected librtmp style URL parameters, these aren't supported by the libavformat internal RTMP handler currently enabled. See the documentation for the correct way to pass parameters.
^C[flv @ 0x3c59b00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[flv @ 0x3c59b00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: none, 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
rtmp://IP/live/1234 live=1: could not find codec parameters
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

I have installed avserver (Libav) earlier to ffmpeg.Kindly suggest any alternative to live=1  or provide suggstion.

Comment: Is it working without the `live=1`? For my modern ffmpeg works with it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for ffmpeg version N-71741-ge2877bd :

```
ffmpeg -rtmp_live live -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56
```